# Devise: Clicking sign in and nothing happening

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, webrick

I can register and remain logged in as the user that has just been created. But once I click sign out and try to sign back in, nothing happens. Here is the server result:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-20 16:44:59 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XzM+pKK4WDDzD2V/jedhR/+E7OKFIBPwIvjTOHCOOZY=", "user"=>{"email"=>"drichards2013@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XzM+pKK4WDDzD2V/jedhR/+E7OKFIBPwIvjTOHCOOZY=", "user"=>{"email"=>"drichards2013@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  Rendered /Users/DylanRichards/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails3tutorial/gems/devise-2.2.4/app/views/devise/shared/_links.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/DylanRichards/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails3tutorial/gems/devise-2.2.4/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (15.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 202ms (Views: 32.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a global before_filter requiring authorization that is blocking the request.

Comment: Okay. What can I do about this?

Comment: Dont set a global before_filter that requires authorized users